# Sharing a Link doesn't post Image

Tags: share, facebook-opengraph

Images aren't being shown when a person shares a URL to our site.
Using the debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and putting in the URL of http://www.muscleandfitness.com/videos/training/workout-101-overhead-pullover-video It shows that the meta tags are correct and an image is shown.

However share this link on Facebook.com and no image is shown.

Using Firebug I can see that the image scraper only returns a 1x1 pixel. 
https://www.facebook.com/ajax/composerx/attachment/link/scraper/?scrape_url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.muscleandfitness.com%252Fvideos%252Ftraining%252Fworkout-101-overhead-pullover-video&composerurihash=2
composerurihash 2
scrape_url  http%3A%2F%2Fwww.muscleandfitness.com%2Fvideos%2Ftraining%2Fworkout-101-overhead-pullover-video
Safe Image returns a 1x1 pixel: https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBBILbPW7Po7Cds&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.muscleandfitness.com%2Fsites%2Fmuscleandfitness.com%2Ffiles%2FOverhead-Pullover_rotator_0.jpg

I need help in fixing this issue so that we can easily share URL's with the image.

Comment: I see the image when I share your URL.

Comment: Correct - the issue seems to be with articles that are posted within the last couple of days. After awhile it starts to work.

Answer (score 0):

Found that adding a trailing slash on the URL makes it work. It also seems to work better if the link comes after some words.

Example: 
Wasn't working: http://www.muscleandfitness.com/news-and-features/features/everything-arnold-february-mf
but this worked: http://www.muscleandfitness.com/news-and-features/features/everything-arnold-february-mf/

Answer (score 0):

I also get into a similar problem. My problem is because of the image name has a "space" in it. so it is not appear in the [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and also in sharing.

So i fixed the issue by replace space with hyphen("-") through coding part. After that i debug the url in [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), it appears. That means Facebook wont show the image name with "space". But there is no logical reason behind this. Anyway it will help someone.

For more information check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216164/3049065) posted by [Patrick D'appollonio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012139/patrick-dappollonio). It helps me.